# How to fix this simple issue?

Tags: django, python-3.x

when i type

```
python manage.py runserver
```

on windows powershell , the django server is working properly but when i tried to run the django server on pycharm, server not connecting and give this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

. How do i fix this error?

here is the snapshot `https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEzUW.png`

Comment: Install django using pycharm.

Answer (score 1):

Is the python version on pycharm the same one that you are using in powershell?

run `python --version` in powershell and go to

File -> Settings

Preferences -> Project Interpreter -> Python Interpreters

on PyCharm and make sure they are the same.

Comment: Sorry, I unable to find the settings as u mentioned?