# pip install locustio ==0.8a2 is not installing?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I got an issue on 'core' module in not find in django project. To overcome from this problem, i got to know that i have to install 'locustio ==0.8a2' so i type in windowshell
   `pip install locustio ==0.8a2`
 but it is not installing.
  And here is the initial problem(django):

```
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Papul\Desktop\sandeep\myproject\myproject\urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from core.views import SignUpView
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

here is the snapshot:[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/00tGl.png  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXO5u.png

Answer (score 0):

"`No module named core`", it looks like could not find your `django` package. please show "`pip list` ", by the way, why not use some IDE to run your project.(e.g. `pycharm` )

Comment: Hi, Actually I can't run the server from pycharm terminal and i don't know why, I already asked this Question { https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649933/how-to-fix-this-simple-issue } and here is the snapshot of pip list { https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVJrr.png }

Answer (score 0):

You should install locust package it's not locustio anymore:

Locust package has moved from 'locustio' to 'locust'. Please update your reference (or pin your version to 0.14.6 if you dont want to update to 1.0)

```
pip install locust
```

Comment: pip installing locust will install the latest locust version, instead of the specific version he is trying to install.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve, install the missing modules:

```
pip install core
```

before you run

```
pip install locustio==0.8a2
```